# Do two antennas need to have the same range in order to communicate?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

If one antenna has a range of say 200 feet and a second antenna has a range of only 20 feet, can communication still occur if the first antenna is outside the 20 feet range of antenna 2?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you define as "communicate" and by "range"? If one antenna is a reception antenna and the other a signal transmission antenna and the reception signal is below the sensitivity threshold of the reception antenna then obviously,there is no communication possible. The same holds for bidirectional signal transmission systems.

In any case range of transmitted signal from both antennas must be within the reception range for each antenna and at a signal strength level above the sensitivity reception threshold.

Also keep in mind that range can be affected by location and landscape (i.e. mountains, interior obstacles etc.) especially for microwave antennas that for long outdoor communications demand [line-of-sight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-of-sight_propagation) between the antennas locations.

Comment: Let's say if it was using a modern bidirectional technology like Bluetooth, would the same apply?

Comment: @Ninja2k Yes. Again, range will be limited by physical obstacles in case of microwaves like Bluetooth. The range give by the manufacturer of the device is approximate. Usually Bluetooth devices rated at 10m will not have problem to communicate even at 15-20 meters away, however with a degraded bit rate.